# Reboot system through cronjob

Tags: python, cron, reboot, raspbian

I'm running a python script as the root user. (I know its not reccomended but in my case its ok.)
At the end of this script, based on some conditions I need to reboot the raspberry.

I have tried several codes but none actually reboots the machine. I have tried this at the end of my .py file:

```
os.system("shutdown -r now")
reboot
sudo reboot
os.system("reboot")
```

None of these reboots the raspberry. What is the proper code to reboot the system?

Comment: (example, if the condition to reboot is 'every' 60 seconds, then the below crontab will work) EDITOR=vi
TERM=vt100
export EDITOR TERM
crontab -e

60 * * * * shutdown -r now

Comment: nope, the condition is a if statement inside the .py file that is executed. i need to reboot from inside the script.

Comment: I just tried and I see that just os.system("shutdown /r")  works fine

Comment: thanks, testing.. will report back.. please post it also as solution so ican accept it if it works.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
import os
os.system('/sbin/shutdown -r now')
```

It's because cron jobs don't have environment, so you have to provide full path to the 'shutdown' program, otherwise the system can not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Just this should work:

```
import os  
os.system("shutdown /r")
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work.. it just doesnt do anything.. no error nor anything. the rest of the code is working properly.

Comment: I'm surprised. I let someone else to give the feedback.

Comment: i guess it is because root user is disabled on the raspberry.. so i think that even if i run it as root it is executed as normal user.. can i run just this comand as root inside the script? just adding sudo doesnt work.